# How to make initials icons using Coil in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

So I am using the Coil library for our image processing and I noticed in the place holder it only takes an int. I want however to display initials if a user does not have an avatar or incase of any error show initials, like this image  see below. Problem is, I am new in jetpack compose and not sure how I can achieve this. See my code below.

[image]

I have this card that has icon, and some details my Profile Card

```
ProfileCard( 
    personName = String.format("%s %s", e.firstName, e.lastName),
    personC = entity.program ?: "", 
    painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(model = getProfileAvatar(entity.id)),
    onCardClick = {})
```

My `getProfileAvatar()`

```
private fun getProfileAvatar(id: String) : ImageRequest {
    val url = ServiceAPI.photoUrl(id) 
    return ImageRequest.Builder(requireContext()) 
        .data(url) 
        .addHeader() ) 
        .build() }
```

Will appreciate feedback, I did see a couple of post, but don't address the Jetpack part.

Answer (score 4):

Coil has no built-in support for composable placeholders.
However you have different options.

You can use the `SubcomposeAsyncImage` using the `painter.state` to define different Composables:

```
SubcomposeAsyncImage(
    model = url,
    contentDescription = "contentDescription",
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    modifier = Modifier.clip(CircleShape)
) {
    val state = painter.state
    if (state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Loading || state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Error) {

        //text with a background circle
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .drawBehind {
                    drawCircle(
                        color = Teal200,
                        radius = this.size.maxDimension
                    )
                },
            text = "NG",
            style = TextStyle(color = Color.White, fontSize = 20.sp)
        )
    } else {
        SubcomposeAsyncImageContent()
    }
```

[image]

Also the `placeholder` parameter in the `AsyncImage` accepts a `Painter`. You can define your custom `TextPainter`

```
AsyncImage(
    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .data(url)
        .build(),
    placeholder = TextPainter(
        circleColor= Teal200,
        textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer(),
        text="NG",
        circleSize = Size(200f, 200f)
    ),
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
)
```

where:

```
class TextPainter(val circleColor: Color,
                  val circleSize : Size,
                  val textMeasurer: TextMeasurer,
                  val text : String,
) : Painter() {

    val textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult =
        textMeasurer.measure(
            text = AnnotatedString(text),
            style = TextStyle(color = Color.White, fontSize = 20.sp)
        )

    override val intrinsicSize: Size get() = circleSize

    override fun DrawScope.onDraw() {
        //the circle background
        drawCircle(
            color = circleColor,
            radius = size.maxDimension/2
        )
        
        val textSize = textLayoutResult.size
        //The text
        drawText(
            textLayoutResult = textLayoutResult,
            topLeft = Offset(
                (this.size.width - textSize.width) / 2f,
                (this.size.height - textSize.height) / 2f
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use coil's [`SubcomposeAsyncImage`](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/#subcomposeasyncimage) for that. It allows you to use any composable function as a placeholder/error state:

```
SubcomposeAsyncImage(
    model = getProfileAvatar()
) {
    val state = painter.state
    if (state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Loading || state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Error) {
        Text(text = "NG")
    } else {
        SubcomposeAsyncImageContent()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

```
val personName by remember{ mutableStateOf(String.format("%s %s", entity.firstName, entity.lastName)) }
val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
    model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
        .allowHardware(false)
        .data("https://xxxx.xxxx.user_avatar.jpg")
        .size(Size.ORIGINAL)
        .build()
)
val isErrorState = painter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Error
val textMeasure = rememberTextMeasurer()
val textLayoutResult = textMeasure.measure(text = buildAnnotatedString { append(personName) }, style = TextStyle(color = Color.White, fontSize = 16.sp))

ProfileCard(
    modifier = Modifier.drawBehind {
        if(isErrorState) {
            drawText(textLayoutResult = textLayoutResult)
        }
    },
    personName = personName,
    personC = entity.program ?: "",
    painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(model = getProfileAvatar(entity.id)),
    onCardClick = {}
)
```

Comment: Where is the ```rememberTextMeasurer()``` coming from? thank in advance.

Comment: How does it shorten the first and second name to initials ?

Comment: Please add implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.3.2" dependency

Comment: How to get the first letter  ：  char first = "your content......".charAt(0);

Comment: sadly this did not work on the Card, it drew the text back and not in the profile card image where is should. The drawText is not called.

Comment: How is written in your ProfileCard

Comment: thank you for helping this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75076781/how-to-properly-handle-loading-initials-as-place-holders-in-jetpack-compose My ProfileCard, has an image, and two texts

Comment: I was stunned by you, but you actually used it incorrectly and set Modifier.drawBehind to @Composable Image